# What are these white connectors called?

Tags: connector, identification

What are these white connectors called?  I'm assuming they have a common name, with different numbers of pins.

Update:  better pictures, showing "BM Z" on the board connector.  The board is identified by the vendor as a "[600TVL Sony Super CCD](http://www.securitycamera2000.com/productimage.php?product_id=2372)" camera.

[image]

[image: close up]

Update:  the pins are 1.25mm center-to-center.  It seems they are part of the Molex Picoblade family.

Sad observation: the connectors are quite cheap (.07 USD in small quantities) but requires a crimping tool that retails for about 200 USD.

Comment: Look at the connectors with a magnifying glass.  May be, there's a name of the manufacturer, or some other text.  If you post the text here, it could help ID the connector.

Comment: The pictures are clearer now. What is the pitch length between pins?

Comment: The crimp tool is worth every penny. Fine-pitch connectors like these are worthless if you try to crimp them with pliers or a knife or solder or whatever. Bad connections are way too fragile.

Comment: Yep, I agree about crimp tools.  I've got a nice one for servo-style connectors and it's been great.  For my immediate needs it will be more cost-effective to buy some pre-crimped pigtails and solder them using the pigtails.  I wish there were some aftermarket crimper sources for connectors like this!

Comment: Disagree about the crimp tool. It's easily possible to crimp them with pliers and solder paste. We do dozens (hundreds?) of them at work, and if they are done right they don't fail. It just takes practice and patience. I can e-mail you detailed instructions if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are "wire-to-board" connector assemblies. You need to look for hints on its brand as the one you have there is a matched mated system. An important specification to aid identification is the pitch or distance between the center-lines of two pins: usually either 0.1in (2.54mm) or 0.156in (3.96mm).

Although the picture is a bit unclear, I think what you have there is a TE 0.1in connector from their CST-100 system. Try this [page](http://www.te.com/catalog/bin/TE.Connect?S=23480&M=PPROP&P=2322&BML=10576,17534,17733&LG=1&PG=1&IDS=390853,13531,390840,390867,390889,390902,390974,56699,56583,56815,56813,99090&N=2) and check if the product photo and the 3D PDF matches your connector.

When faced with an unknown connector, try exploring catalogs like the one from [RS](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/general-purpose/) or TE's [picture search](http://www.te.com/picturesearch/).

Comment: thanks for the RS and TE picture search links.  those will come in handy in the future search of connectors !

Comment: yes, the picture search links are great!

Answer (score 6):

These particular connectors look like [JST](http://www.jst.com) connectors to me. However, they also resemble some [Hirose](http://www.hirose.com) connectors as well. Can you get a better image? With a better image I might be able to pick out the particular connector series.

Comment: Thanks!  I've updated with an iphone pic which I hope is a bit better...

Comment: Hmmm... hard to gauge... but that looks like Hirose's DF13 part to me. Take a look at the datasheet and see if the measurements agree. http://www.hirose.co.jp/cataloge_hp/e53600014.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Should be Molex PicoBlade, serilized as 53047xx10. xx stand for the # of pins. As above mentioned, you could do the crimping with plier and soldering if you just work on small volume.